# Maven dependancy issue, even with sample code

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to learn the Spring LDAP framework, and I decided to download some sample code to play around with. Unfortunately, when ever I try to build any code (including direct clones from GitHub), I get this error when I run

`mvn clean install`

Error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project spring-ldap-plain-sample: There are test failures.
```

I have searched for other people with the same issues, and none of them have helped me.

Here is the latest repo I tried to run

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap

Comment: You have tests error, either fix them or skip the tests : http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: Yes, skipping the tests does indeed help, but I don't understand how I can get constant test errors if I am copying the code directly from something else.

Comment: Maybe your local configuration doesn't match theirs, look at the failed test and check the exact errors (you probably have some /target/surefire subdirectory where you will find the errors) .

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot. He was on Spring version 4.3.3 and I was on 4.3.4. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

try to download newest maven version
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

set it and run it again! :)